# robust standard errors for mixed-effects models in lme4 package of R

Tags: r, mixed-models

I am using the lme4 package for linear mixed effect modeling

the mixed-effect model is below:

```
fm01 <- lmer(sublat <- goal + (1|userid))
```

the above command returns an S4 object called fm01

this object includes fixed effects and their OLS standard errors (below)

```
Fixed effects:

            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   31.644      3.320   9.530
goaltypeF1    -4.075      3.243  -1.257
goaltypeF2    -9.187      5.609  -1.638
goaltypeF3   -13.935      9.455  -1.474
goaltypeF4   -20.219      8.196  -2.467
goaltypeF5   -12.134      8.797  -1.379"
```

however, i need to provide robust standard errors

How can I do this with an S4 object such as returned by lme4?

Comment: something like [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/poissonreg.htm)?

Comment: Excatly, but for a *mixed-effects* regression. Unfortunately, vcovHC(model, type="HC0") does not work on those model outputs. You can obtain vcov(model) but you cannot obtain vcovHC(model).

Comment: you (or someone) would need to look at `vignette("sandwich-OOP",package="sandwich")` and figure out how to write `estfun.merMod` and `bread.merMod` functions, starting from `sandwich:::estfun.lm` and `sandwich:::bread.lm` and adapting as necessary.

Comment: [merDeriv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merDeriv/index.html) package and [clubSandwich](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clubSandwich/index.html) package would do some help in extracting some components for sandwich robust standard errors and hypothesis test.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like robust SEs for `lmerMod` objects are available via the `merDeriv` and `clubSandwich` packages:

```r
library(lme4)
library(clubSandwich)
m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
```

### using merDeriv

(From the replication materials of the [merDeriv JSS paper](https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v087.c01), thanks to @AchimZeileis for the tip)

```r
library(merDeriv)
sand <- sandwich(m, bread = bread(m, full = TRUE),
         mean = meat(m, level = 2))
```

### clubSandwich

(all possible types: I don't know enough to know which is 'best' in any given case)

```r
cstypes <- paste0("CR", c("0", "1", "1p", "1S", "2", "3"))
rob_se_fun <- function(type) sqrt(diag(vcovCR(m, type = type)))
rob_se <- sapply(cstypes, rob_se_fun)
```

### combine results

```r
std_se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(m)))
cbind(std = std_se, rob_se,
      merDeriv = sqrt(diag(sand)[1:2]))\
```

```
                 std      CR0      CR1     CR1p     CR1S      CR2      CR3
(Intercept) 6.824597 6.632277 6.824557 7.034592 6.843700 6.824557 7.022411
Days        1.545790 1.502237 1.545789 1.593363 1.550125 1.545789 1.590604
            merDeriv
(Intercept) 6.632277
Days        1.502237
```

`merDeriv`'s results match `type="CR0"` (merDeriv provides robust Wald estimates for *all* components, including the random effect parameters; it's up to you to decide if Wald estimates for RE parameters are reliable enough)

Comment: In the replication materials of the `merDeriv` paper in JSS (https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v087.c01), the authors show how to combine their package with `sandwich`. You have to indicate the specific flavor of `bread()` and `estfun()` explicitly: `sandwich(m, bread = bread(m, full = TRUE), meat = meat(m, level = 2))`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustlmm/vignettes/rlmer.pdf

It's the `robustlmm` package, which has the `rlmer` function.

"The structure of the objects and the methods are implemented to be as similar as possible to the ones of lme4 with robustness specific extensions where needed."

```
fm01_rob <- rlmer(sublat <- goal + (1|userid))
```

Comment: This is a different meaning of "robust" than the OP means ...