# Estimate CIs with robust variance poisson mixed model

Tags: r, multi-level, poisson, robust

I am trying to estimate confidence intervals for a mixed effects poisson model using robust standard errors in R. I followed [these instructions](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/poisson-regression/) and was able to estimate confidence intervals for a model without random effects.

Now, I would like to estimate confidence intervals with robust standard errors for a poisson model, with a random term. It seems like the sandwich command does not work for `glmer`, only `glm`. I have not been able to find a good solution yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412581/robust-standard-errors-for-mixed-effects-models-in-lme4-package-of-r

Comment: see link from now-deleted answer there: http://courses.education.illinois.edu/EdPsy587/Lectures/6%20inference1/R_robust_standard_errors_v6.txt