# Robust standard errors for mixed effects models in R

Tags: r, lme4

I understand that you cannot fit a glmer(via "lme4") then test using robust SE estimator.

Ie

```
model <- glmer(Sepal.Length ~ Species * Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + (1 | grp), data = restricted2, family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

then do

```
coeftest(model, vcov = sandwich)
```

Is there any other packages that allow you to do the same using lme4 packages?

I've had a look at merDeriv package but I'm still not to sure how to go about this.

Comment: Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412581/robust-standard-errors-for-mixed-effects-models-in-lme4-package-of-r It doesn't do the tests, but it does set up the robust SEs for you ...