# Issue with getting robust SEs using Sandwich, merDeriv and glmer of lme4

Tags: r, standard-error

I would like to get robust estimate of standard error for glmer of lme4. I used the following code that combines sandwich and merDeriv, which previously worked, but now I get an error:

```r
a = lme4::glmer(gholocaust ~ cg06131859_KYNU + IC + gender + age+ (1|cID), 
     data = data, 
     family = "binomial", nAGQ = 5L)
sandwich::sandwich(a, bread. = bread.glmerMod, meat. = meat(a, level = 2))
```

the error message is:

> Error in (function (cond) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': subscript out of bounds

If I run only the first line, it is okay:

```r
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Adaptive Gauss-Hermite Quadrature, nAGQ = 5) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: gholocaust ~ cg06131859_KYNU + IC + gender + age + (1 | cID)
   Data: data
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
136.2090 151.4046 -62.1045 124.2090       87 
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Std.Dev.
 cID    (Intercept) 0.5122  
Number of obs: 93, groups:  cID, 47
Fixed Effects:
    (Intercept)  cg06131859_KYNU               IC        genderאשה              age  
        2.53816         -5.72758         -0.83361          0.61304          0.00775  
>
```

The bread part of merDeriv works fine too:

```r
    (Intercept) cg06131859_KYNU           IC   genderאשה          age cov_cID.(Intercept)
[1,]  729.518988    -384.5030066 -320.5693995 -17.1856860 -10.10491538         -3.45021545
[2,] -384.503007     530.5340435  181.3728027 -16.2948357   0.57913609        -34.97224468
[3,] -320.569399     181.3728027  284.3496470   4.7488551   0.23081025         17.61985923
[4,]  -17.185686     -16.2948357    4.7488551  11.0148593   0.50889828          5.55635382
[5,]  -10.104915       0.5791361    0.2308103   0.5088983   0.32781282          0.02613785
[6,]   -3.450215     -34.9722447   17.6198592   5.5563538   0.02613785         57.24944251
```

Any ideas for the error message?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could we please have a [mcve]?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412581/robust-standard-errors-for-mixed-effects-models-in-lme4-package-of-r/70268157#70268157