# Calculating Inflated/Robust Standard Errors with lme4

Tags: r, lme4

So, in my study two groups of participants were asked to make ratings under two conditions over 60 trials. I am using a linear mixed effects model to compare change in prediction errors across groups and within-subject condition. Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
structure(list(subject = c("5f556bd46e6c4c93a5a90c77", "5f49891aeb2e884fb829b84f", 
"5f63d462fb4c4713b69d4bb7", "6170406b453e66204b8beed3", "5faed13122118306ee26cede", 
"5f2a5f187bf471245f7dc096", "5f2226ed22f0956bf55ddb71", "61086f515114c26363323a17", 
"5f70c532da8e516a8ccca1da", "60730cdbbc89ec27b9cc7acd", "5f49891aeb2e884fb829b84f", 
"5ffc78b5223b4e0ad272bbc8", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21", "6282abf0be2e9e2a65af807e", 
"5e7f514bb18cb4000a68310d", "5ea35bfe13923f2ca4ce450b", "5f3c48bea714e02094c9d0ae", 
"5e8c014d07f0e10f04ab5072", "5f0bd6bcb4630b4f73ab47a3", "5db3b031efa9f6000cf02400", 
"5dcc1eb66f3f168a9515c150", "5f9b014daee4da2af5391e54", "5f822b965e9c003467ca37ec", 
"5f0082e67535f20164d33b15", "5db3b031efa9f6000cf02400", "60f36509e33b5a8da6a56bd7", 
"60382d89160c3e15cc2cb369", "5ee9f0fa87dec101cd15d4c4", "5e5323c8c9f6063449ad9f00", 
"5f50dc440305bb077d82eca4", "5f86785f5737541cf77a12b9", "5cf5d7529681010001eeaecf", 
"5f4fc8c618bf9a0daf3f211d", "5ef90b249bafa50a311593ae", "5db3b031efa9f6000cf02400", 
"5f0082e67535f20164d33b15", "5eaef287fb863f5c922abad9", "5ee0c244c68c754255de45dc", 
"5f3c48bea714e02094c9d0ae", "5e7f514bb18cb4000a68310d", "610801fd0be0f507ef34e1be", 
"6101930ddd5330f83b898c61", "60382d89160c3e15cc2cb369", "5f6c102b6ec04317fc9a8127", 
"5ec2ccabec26b70d7d0be8d5", "5ee00907ed486334f7063e3a", "5f2e0b28c642b31678638a21", 
"5f8a42a274d4140fdb262d1f", "60548f4c7e12da7443c545ae", "5f1338a87447d0308e865fd0"
), image = c("ice_skates_04", "chicken_2", "berries_03", "kiwi_01", 
"gratin_01", "skateboard_03", "skateboard_02", "drums_3", "ball_01", 
"ice_skates_02", "microscope_2", "orange_01", "wrap_01", "bun_1", 
"asian_02", "beads_1", "frisbee_2", "snorkling_02", "ribbon_1", 
"notebook_1", "ball_02", "cucumber_01", "taco_01", "skateboard_03", 
"dice_1", "camera_1", "bike_01", "berries_03", "burger_02", "boomerang_1", 
"notebook_2", "notebook_1", "cake3", "ice_skates_02", "headphones_3", 
"cam_corder_1", "bacon_toast_01", "ice_skates_02", "cucumber_01", 
"chips_03", "candy_1", "tennis_03", "ball_02", "guitar_2", "candy_1", 
"candy_3", "notebook_4", "microscope_2", "ball_02", "oil_3"), 
    trial = c(19L, 58L, 48L, 52L, 26L, 56L, 51L, 37L, 40L, 44L, 
    35L, 11L, 37L, 22L, 41L, 41L, 2L, 53L, 55L, 38L, 36L, 43L, 
    18L, 43L, 43L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 47L, 15L, 44L, 40L, 54L, 18L, 
    23L, 30L, 4L, 11L, 50L, 45L, 6L, 55L, 9L, 46L, 8L, 16L, 7L, 
    12L, 19L, 4L), condition = c("odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", 
    "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", "mean", "odd", "odd", 
    "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", 
    "odd", "mean", "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd", 
    "odd", "mean", "mean", "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", 
    "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "odd", "odd", 
    "mean", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "mean"), learn_prof = c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), PE = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L)), row.names = c(12436L, 
10965L, 12620L, 21797L, 15903L, 10190L, 9829L, 20818L, 13213L, 
17234L, 10999L, 16411L, 120L, 22227L, 5766L, 6256L, 10742L, 5992L, 
8865L, 3085L, 3494L, 14812L, 13675L, 8510L, 3053L, 19475L, 16581L, 
7940L, 4828L, 12143L, 13886L, 1645L, 11672L, 8234L, 3071L, 8433L, 
6730L, 7874L, 10732L, 5806L, 20677L, 20397L, 16574L, 13028L, 
7357L, 7718L, 10408L, 14119L, 16814L, 9329L), class = "data.frame")
```

...and accompanying linear mixed effects model:

```
TD_PE_analysis1 <- lmer(PE ~  learn_prof * trial * condition + (1|subject) + (1|image), data=dat)
```

PE refers prediction error, learn_prof refers to the two groups, trial is 1-60, and condition is the 2 within subject conditions. We also include random effects of subject and image. Prior to running the model, I found, using the fligner test, that our two learning profile groups had significantly different distributions of PEs. To address this potential violation of assumptions, it was suggested that I implement robust standard errors instead of the default. I found a post here that I will link below about implementing merDeriv and clubSandwich but I am not entirely sure I fully understand what is going on with this suggestion much less implement it in my code. How would I set this up to compute robust standard errors for my data?

[robust standard errors for mixed-effects models in lme4 package of R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412581/robust-standard-errors-for-mixed-effects-models-in-lme4-package-of-r)

Comment: I tried the methods listed in that post for your example; both of them (`merDeriv` and `clubSandwich`) give errors reporting that robust SEs can't be computed (at least for the approaches implemented in those packages) for models with multiple (`merDeriv`) or non-nested (`clubSandwich`) clustering variables ... this may turn into a [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) question, if you need to figure out **what** to do before you can try to figure out **how** to do it ...

Comment: Just a quick offshoot question, there is also this robustlmm package where you can run rlmer, does this compute robust standard errors? The earlier post seemed to indicate it does not but I want to double check

Comment: It estimates *effects* robustly; it doesn't compute robust standard errors (AFAIK).

Comment: Ah so probably not what I am looking for exactly

Comment: You could report bootstrap CIs instead; there's `lme4::bootMer()`, though I couldn't find in the documentation how the random effects and clustering are accounted for.